# Making a module inherit from another module in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module, inheritance

I'm making a small program for Rails that includes some of my methods I've built inside of a module inside of the `ApplicationHelper` module. Here's an example:

```
module Helper
    def time
        Time.now.year
    end
end

module ApplicationHelper
    # Inherit from Helper here...
end
```

I know that `ApplicationHelper < Helper` and `include Helper` would work in the context of a class, but what would you use for module-to-module inherits? Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In fact you *can* define a module inside of another module, and then **include** it within the outer one.

```
so ross$ cat >> mods.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  module Helper
    def time
      Time.now.year
    end
  end
  include Helper
end

class Test
  include ApplicationHelper
  def run
    p time
  end
  self
end.new.run
so ross$ ruby mods.rb
2012
```

Comment: I never thought about using a module inside of another one, thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure what declaring Helper inside ApplicationHelper does, other than hide it from global code.  The important thing is that 'include' (and 'extend') works for modules as well as classes.

Comment: This is not inheritance..  You can't use super here. 
If the applicationHelper had a run method, the class just removed it.

Answer (score 5):

One potential gotcha is that if the included module attaches class methods, then those methods may be attached to the wrong object.

In some cases, it may be safer to include the 'parent' module directly on the base class, then include another module with the new methods. e.g.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      include Helper
      include InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def new_method
      #..
    end
  end

end
```

The new methods are not defined directly in `ApplicationHelper` as the `include Helper` would be run after the method definitions, causing them to be overwritten by `Helper`. One could alternatively define the methods inside the `class_eval` block

Comment: Here you have the include statements inside your method definition, which probably isn't the right way to do it...  This is a good warning against writing includes inside method definitions.  The include should be outside the method definition as in DigitalRoss' answer